# Building MRAA for Java on Pi 2 B (raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, rpi.gpio

i'm trying to use the MRAA lib to program the pins with java, but when I built the files, I can't find where the path was set, idealy it would be set on /usr/lib, but there's no mraa. Without it I can't compile the Java files that include mraa and load mraajava.

PS: I folowed the guide on the [gitHub page](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa/blob/master/docs/building.md) and built with the following flags on the `cmake` line:

`-DBUILDSWIGNODE=OFF` `-DBUILDSWIGPYTHON=OFF` `-DBUILDARCH=arm` `-DBUILDSWIGJAVA=ON`

Have someone been able to successfully build the java files for tha Raspberry 2 B on the raspbian?

EDIT: Solved! After a close look at the Cmake error log, I realized that JAVA_HOME was somehow not exported and after a simple `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk 8` everything worked.